Every vertex in G has a vertex at a distance greater than 2. Prove: there is a vertex within distance 2 of every other vertex in the complement of G.
In a general graph, every vertex has a vertex at a distance greater than 2. Prove: there is a vertex within distance 2 of every other vertex in the complement of G.
Here is my verification:
Let d denotes the distance in graph G, d' denotes the distance in G'(the complement of G), u and v denote two distinct vertexes in G the distance between which denoted by d(u,v) is the diameter of G denoted by diam(G). Then we can get that d(u,v) ≥ 2. Then for every vertex x in G there exists another vertex y satisfying d(x,y) ≥ 2. We can split u,v,x,y into two components which are not connected mutually in G such as {u,x} and {v,y}. There isn't an edge between u and y, x and v, u and v or x and y in G. So there is an edge between u and y, x and v, u and v or x and y in G'. In G', u and x have a common neighbor v, so d'(u,x) ≤ 2. Then u is the vertex we want to find.
I'm not sure whether the proof is right.
